# PyTorch : error message "torch has no [...] member"

Tags: pytorch

Good evening,
I have just installed PyTorch 0.4.0 and I'm trying to carry out the first tutorial "What is PyTorch?"
I have written a Tutorial.py file which I try to execute with Visual Studio Code

Here is the code :

```
from __future__ import print_function
import torch

print (torch.__version__)

x = x = torch.rand(5, 3)
print(x)
```

Unfortunately, when I try to debug it, i have an error message :
"torch has no rand member"

This is true with any member function of torch I may try

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: What is the result from `print(torch.__version__)`?

Comment: Also what is the result from `print(torch.__path__)`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, here are the results :
0.4.0
['D:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\torch']

Comment: same issue here.

Answer (score 82):

*In case you haven't got a solution to your problem or someone else encounters it.*

The error is raised because of Pylint (*Python static code analysis tool*) not recognizing `rand` as the member function. You can either configure Pylint to *ignore* this problem or you can whitelist torch (*better solution*) to remove lint errors by adding following to your `.pylintrc` file.

```
[TYPECHECK]

# List of members which are set dynamically and missed by Pylint inference
# system, and so shouldn't trigger E1101 when accessed.
generated-members=numpy.*, torch.*
```

In Visual Studio Code, you could also add the following to the user settings:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
"--generated-members=numpy.* ,torch.*"
]
```

The issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/701) on PyTorch GitHub page.

Comment: as soon as I do this either with a .pylintrc or VSCode settings, the errors go away but pylint complains more like missing docstrings, etc.

Comment: @AmirHosseinF see the Github issue, there's additional args to suppress other warning except errors

Comment: To be clear, this goes in `settings.json` which can be accessed with File -> Preferences -> Settings then editing the settings in the text editor.

Comment: This doesn't work for me using VSCode 1.50.1 and PyTorch 1.7.0

Comment: Can you configure something similar to selectively ignore `import-error` and/or `no-name-in-module` errors for a specific subset of packages?

Answer (score 6):

Fast solution from [pylint no member issue but code still works vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844378/pylint-no-member-issue-but-code-still-works-vscode)

```
Press: CTRL + Shift + P

Click on "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)"

Add this line into JSON : "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--generate-members"]
```

Comment: PyLint has no parameter `generate-members`. Did you mean to pass use `--generated-members torch` as in the answer above?

Comment: I only added the line 
`"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--generate-members"]`
to the settings.json file and that was sufficient for me. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still facing the problem then here is the solution that worked for me.
Go to vs code settings, `file>preferences>settings` or use shortcut `ctrl+,` and search for `python.linting.pylintPath`.
Modify the pylint path, Go to your `anaconda installation directory>pkgs>pylint>scripts` and copy paste the path to the settings and add `pylint` at the end of the path, something like this `(anaconda installation directory)\pkgs\pylint-2.4.4-py37_0\Scripts\pylint`

Answer (score 1):

This argument (`python.linting.pylintArgs`) seems to have been changed to the following:

```
"pylint.args": [
  "--generated-members=torch.*, numpy.*"
]
```

I'm on ubuntu 22.04, vscode 1.85.1.

Answer (score -6):

In VS Code, one can select flake8 by

> Ctrl + Shift + P -> Select linter -> flake8

[Source](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/701)