# pylint no member issue but code still works vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I have a very simple code here

```
import torch

l = torch.nn.Linear(2,5)
v = torch.FloatTensor([1, 2])
print(l(v))
```

under `torch.FloatTensor`, pylint in visual studio code claims that 'Module torch has no 'FloatTensor' member pylint(no-member).

However, the code works fine. Is this a false positive? How can I disable pylint for this specific instance?

Comment: Is it an option to switch to a different linter?  Similar errors went away for me when I switched to flake8 in vscode: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> `Python: Select Linter`->`flake8`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

1. Press: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Click on "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)"
3. Add this line into JSON :
   `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--generated-members", "from_json,query"]`

---

Comment: Does this really work, though? I edited my JSON with that and pylint stopped working completely.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my issue on Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @RGS, It worked for me. Are you sure you didn't forget the comma at the end of the line above where you inserted the line from #3 above?

Comment: @SoCalCoder I am... :/

Comment: @SoCalCoder, is it possible that you forgot the 'd' in '--generated-members'? I believe there's a typo in the answer above.

Comment: @StevenDarnell it is a typo indeed. According to pylint's help message (`pylint --long-help`) it should be `--generated-members=member1,member2,member3`.
So, correct line in VSCode's settings JSON should be `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--generated-members", "from_json,query"]`

Answer (score 11):

What worked for me was noticing what modules were giving those errors, which is `torch` for you, and then followed these steps:

1. hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. click on "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)"
3. add the following to the JSON file you are presented with:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--generated-members", "torch.*"
]
```

for the sake of this answer, say that there were other modules giving problems, then you'd write:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--generated-members", "torch.* other_module.* next_module.*"
]
```

Comment: I'm quite late to this post but this is the answer that worked for me. The currently accepted answer just seemed to break my PyLint setup, so yes the warning went away but so did all checking.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is a problem of Pylint.

If you use Anaconda, you can do:

1. search `python.linting.pylintPath` in your VSCode setting
2. change it to `(Your Anaconda Path)\pkgs\pylint-1.8.4-py36_0\Scripts\pylint`

`Your Anaconda Path` and `pylint-1.8.4-py36_0` may vary.

Comment: Could anyone share more details about this? I cannot find the `Scripts` directory under my `(You Anaconda Path)\pkgs\pylint-xxx-xxx` path.

Comment: @Boooooooooms Same! Could you please let me know how did you fixed this issue? Thanks!

Comment: This one solve my problem. VS code updated and pointed my pylint to the base version instead of the environment version. I try modifiying the setting json and that did not work

Comment: The Scripts folder exist in Windows, Not sure if in a different OS will be different. In general you are looking the pylint.exe. If it is not there then I think you need to `pip intall pylint `

Answer (score 1):

**Here's the 2023 answer:**

```
"pylint.args": [
    "\"--generated-members\", \"torch.*\""
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer seems to be outdated. VS Code does not recognise the key "python.linting.pylintArgs". Use "pylint.args" instead.

```
"pylint.args": ["--generated-members", "torch.*"]
```

Answer (score 0):

A better answer to this question here: [Why does it say that module pygame has no init member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50569453/why-does-it-say-that-module-pygame-has-no-init-member)

The answer above marked as the answer with references to Anaconda doesn't make sense to me, probably a newbie issue.

Please follow the link to get the real scoop, but to summarize -

Replacing *extensionname* with your problem module name, such as pygame or RPi or Torch:

1. Hit CTRL + Shift + P
2. Click on "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)"
3. Add the following to the JSON file you are presented with (inside the {}, if there are entries already there add leading comma as well):

   "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
   "--extension-pkg-whitelist=extensionname" // comma separated
   ]

Answer (score 0):

As Tomari says, it does work on windows.There is a little difference on linux. The path maybe like "(You Anaconda Path)/pkgs/pylint-2.6.0-py38_0/bin/pylint".