# Module 'torch' has no 'empty' member Error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I am getting the following error in V.S. Code after importing torch and running the following code:-

```
Module 'torch' has no 'empty' member pylint(no-member)
```

Code:-

```
x = torch.empty(3) 
print(x)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks:)

Comment: What does `print(torch.__version__)` return?

Comment: @yudhiesh It returns 1.7.1

Comment: I am on 1.5.1 and this works as expected and according to the documentation it is available in your version.

Comment: Are you using VS Code? If so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50319943/pytorch-error-message-torch-has-no-member) might answer your question.

Comment: @yudhiesh Yes I am on V.S. Code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyTorch : error message "torch has no \[...\] member"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50319943/pytorch-error-message-torch-has-no-member)

Comment: @GinoMempin Where shall I add the code in V.S. Code as mentioned in the link provided by you? Thanks!

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53572939/2745495) in that proposed duplicate mentions a few places. There is also VS Code docs on Pylint and Pylint configuration options: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_pylint