# Pytorch in V.S. Code: torch.tensor is not callable

Tags: python, pytorch

I am running my pytorch program in V.S. Code, but, I am getting the following errors:-

```
torch.tensor is not callable
```

I have followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53572939/13218692 and added the following lines in my Settings.json file in V.S. Code, but, I am still getting an error. Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you change the environment in vscode to your in interpreter tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line after it: `,"--disable-msg=not-callable"`
just like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcDeq.png)

Comment: Won't that turn off that not-callable check for ALL code, not just pytorch?

Comment: You can add library that you need in "--generated-members= ",like "numpy.*, cv.*, cv2.*",ect.